# Verify multiple comboboxes/textboxes have value

Tags: vb.net

I have a winform that has about 6 comboboxes and 3 textboxes.  I also have a button that takes the values of aforementioned controls and inserts them into SQL.  Is there a better way, than a bunch of nested if/then statements, to verify that the controls all have values before inserting the data? This gets ugly very fast.  I have tried googling this answer, but I get too many ASPx answers.  I will entertain any ideas you may have.  I am just trying to find a better way to do this.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you group all the controls of same types in an array, then you can easily loop through them and can set the properties of all of them directly by applying it to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not too hard.

This code shows error message about the first empty textbox or combobox. But you can easily modify to show error message for all empty comboboxes and textboxes if required.

```
Private Function ValidateMyControls() As Boolean
    Dim allComboBoxes() As ComboBox = {ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3} ' add all your comboboxes here
    Dim allTextBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}      ' add all your textboxes here

    Dim emptyTB As TextBox = allTextBoxes.Where(Function(f) f.Text = "").FirstOrDefault
    Dim emptyCB As ComboBox = allComboBoxes.Where(Function(f) f.SelectedIndex = -1).FirstOrDefault
    If emptyTB IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill value in " & emptyTB.Name)
        Return False
    ElseIf emptyCB IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a value in dropdown " & emptyCB.Name)
        Return False
    Else
        ' All set to go!
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That works great. I may post back here if I can't figure out how to make it work for all combos/texts.  Thank you very much for your help. I really do appreciate it.